# Why I can add method with default argument to event Action?

Tags: c#, methods, delegates, mono

Consider class

```
class FirstClass 
{
    //Some fields, ctors and methods
    ...
    public event Action Test
    {
        add
        {
            var method = value.Method;
            var parameters = method.GetParameters (); //Count == 1
            // (1)
            //I don't know anything about value so I think I can pass null as argument list because it's Action, not Action<T>
            //And we get Reflection.TargetParameterCountException here.
            method.Invoke (value.Target, null); 
            //Instead of calling Invoke as done above, we should call it like that:
            // (2)
            method.Invoke (value.Target, new object[] { null });
            //But since it's Action, we should be able to call it with (1) not with (2)
        }
        remove
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

And another class

```
class SecondClass
{
    public void TestMethod (Action action = null)
    {
        ...
    }
    public void OtherMethod ()
    {
        var a = new FirstClass ();
        a.Test += TestMethod;
    }
}
```

IMHO: adding method with default arguments to delegate without parameters shouldn't be allowed at type system level.
Why it is allowed?

**P.S.** You could do this not only in add { } accessor but in any other place, code above is just example.

Comment: I've tried your code and the compiler throws an error on the a.Test += TestMethod line stating that it's not allowed because TestMethod does not match delegate System.Action. Are you sure that your code compiles?

Comment: You can't compile that? http://pastie.org/7277752

Comment: No, that won't compile. I'm using Visual Studio 2012 and I get the compile error 'No overload for 'TestMethod' matches delegate 'System.Action''. Changing the event declaration to public event Action<Action> TestEvent fixes the compile error.

Comment: Well, I'm using MonoDevelop, so maybe it's just mono bug/feature.

Answer (score 0):

This should not compile.

Delegate Action has a signate of zero parameters, and no return value:

```
public delegate void Action();
```

So only methods with zero parameters and not return values can be assigned to it. Your second class `SecondClass.TestMethod` does have an argument of type `Action` (to make it all confusing, I guess ;)). So that method would be compatible with another Action delegate (where T = Action):

```
public delegate void Action<T>();
```

If you even do try to manage to call FirstClass.Test.Add, and you try to make the two Invoke-calls, the first one should fail.

Why? The method is a `MethodInfo` of `SecondClass.TestMethod`. This method requires at least one parameter. This parameter must be inside the object-array given to the invoke method. But, in your first call, you do not have an object-array; your object array is set to null. And an object-array set to null cannot hold anything, not even 0 elements, let alone 1 element having null.

The second Invoke does have an object-array with one element, having null.